# github: Everytime i rebase, Unexpected and already merged files comes to my Pull request

Tags: git, github

I am suffering from some issues every time I rebase.
For example, I create a pull request with one commit and one file. Then I have to add a new feature that needs some changes already merged into the master branch (during my development in a separate branch) and rebase.
When I do this, many files appear in my PR. they are part of others commit, but they are already merged to the master.
So my question is how can I avoid this behavior? what I am missing?

Comment: When you are rebasing your branch with master in git, is your master up-to-date ? If not head for your branch would be pointing to old master resulting in already merged changes showing up in PR's.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it was a bug related to my current git version. After an upgrade it seems it's solved.
I will keep you updated with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, as commented, to update your local master first, in order to get all the changes.

Assuming Git 2.23+

```
git switch master
git pull
git switch my-pr-branch
git rebase master
git push --force
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did before rebase. The problem is not that. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @aepelman Can you do a `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --branches` and see where your pr-branch is in that graph?